# Functional and Non-Functional Requirements For Train Tracking Project

Tags: gps, constraints, tracking, gsm, requirements

I am currently developing a project document for my assignment. The title of my project is 'Systematic Train Tracker'.

Let me describe about my system:

The GPS receiver on the train will get the trains information and pass it to the control server using GSM Network. Then the control server will transmit the information to the train administrative office for monitoring purpose. Then the information will also passed to particular stations to display it to passengers.

So what will be the functional and non-functional requirements for my project? And what are the possible constraints will be??

Please help.

Comment: Flagged as "Too broad": There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: small answers with point form is enough. Long answers are not a must.

Comment: Do you know what functional and non-functional requirements are?  Read a textbook, or google them, and then try to apply them to your problem.

Comment: I did like you said. But the correctness is the problem. I am not sure whether the answer is correct or not. That's why i need a expert's answer for clarification.

Comment: Well, firstly Stack Overflow is for coding problems.  And secondly, people usually want to see what you have done, and then they will try to help you.  You'd have a better chance of getting an answer if you posted your requirements and asked if you have classified them correctly.  This question might be a better fit on the Programmers website (see under Stack Exchange on the toolbar above).